# Is it possible to break in GDB only with the condition, not associated with a line, func, etc?

Tags: debugging, gdb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GDB: break if variable equal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390256/gdb-break-if-variable-equal-value)

Is it possible to break in GDB only with the condition, not associated with a line, func, etc?

Its ok if we do:
`break 1699 if m_foo != 0`
m_foo will be evaluated only in line 1699.

but not if we do:
`break ... if m_foo != 0`

How to evaluate the attribute's value during execution, if cond is true then, break, on wherever it is.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390256/gdb-break-if-variable-equal-value/14390352#14390352

Comment: just what I wanted, thank you. I searched with break cond if, etc, that's why I didn't find, should search for `watch`, thanks @Nick .