# How to locate where a type and variable is first declared with gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

When debugging C code with gdb, I often have to find where things are first declared, whether a **type** (structure) or a **variable**. According to this answer ( [GDB: break if variable equal value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14390352/2412518) ) it might not be possible in gdb. Is this true?

If it's not possible in gdb, are there other strategies? I have often used `grep`, but this fails if there are too many results.

Answer (score 3):

> I often have to find where things are first declared, whether a type (structure) or a variable.

Declared or defined ([What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration))? If defined then these commands are available:

Examining the Symbol Table (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbols.html#Symbols) (if compiled with -g):

`info types regexp` lists all source files where a type is defined.

`info variables regexp` - prints the names and data types of all variables (except for local variables) whose names contain a match for regular expression regexp.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can see where this would be helpful at times, although of course this doesn't tell me where things are first defined. I suppose it's not possible.