# GDB: Watch a variable in a given scope

Tags: c, gdb

With GDB I can `watch i`, to break whenever `i` changes. The problem is that I have multiple functions using the name `i`, so GDB breaks inside of all those functions.

Is it possible to break whenever `i` changes, but only inside a given function?

Comment: Please show us a transcript of your interaction with GDB. When I `watch i` inside of a function, GDB (correctly) deletes the watchpoint as soon as I return from that function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set persistent and conditional watchpoints on locally scoped variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354637/how-do-i-set-persistent-and-conditional-watchpoints-on-locally-scoped-variables)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are ***watching a global variable*** and hence it stops in all functions where this variable is modified ***which is the logical and expected behaviour***. If you want to break only inside a given function whenever `i` changes, dont set the breakpoint for `i`. Instead set a breakpoint for the desired function. When this breakpoint is hit, **now** set the watch for `i` so that you know for sure that the next breakpoint will be hit when `i` is modified in the desired function (Ignoring possible recursions and the like)

I guessed that you may not be watching a local variable inside every function with the same name because ***you cannot set a breakpoint on a local variable until you are in the scope of that particular function.***