# Debugging - detect a function writing a memory location

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I need to know if there is a way with linux debugger gdb to detect if a function (any function) of a specific C++ class (represented by file Chord.cc) access a specific memory location (let's say 0xffffbc).
That will help me a lot.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[GDB watchpoints](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) are what you're looking for:

Quote from that page:

> You can use a watchpoint to stop execution whenever the value of an
>   expression changes, without having to predict a particular place where
>   this may happen. (This is sometimes called a data breakpoint.) The
>   expression may be as simple as the value of a single variable, or as
>   complex as many variables combined by operators. Examples include:
>
> - A reference to the value of a single variable.
> - An address cast to an appropriate data type. For example, `*(int
>     *)0x12345678' will watch a 4-byte region at the specified address (assuming an int occupies 4 bytes).

You can then try to apply the techniques from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532860/1298153) to make it a conditional watchpoint, and see if you can find a way to restrict it to particular function calls from that class. You may also find [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336403/is-there-any-way-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-gdb-that-is-conditional-on-the-call-stac) relevant in that respect.