# How can I see the point when a condition stops being met in gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb

A variable value changes to something unreasonable, but there is too many subroutines to manually find where the change happens. How can I use gdb to find the point when a condition (eg. "x<1") is no longer true?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [watchpoint](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html).

You can use a watchpoint to stop execution whenever the value of an expression changes, without having to predict a particular place where this may happen. (This is sometimes called a data breakpoint.)

Comment: And you can add condition to watchpoint, if you don't want to see every change (thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354637/watchpoint-in-gdb has example)